# How do you listen for messages while the app is running in the background?

Tags: firebase

How do you listen for firebase messages while the ios app is running in the background?

How can I check for new messages while the ios app is running in the background?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase SDK uses iOS's underlying sockets, so the library will report new messages as long as the OS keeps the socket open. This can depend on the configuration of your app. If it is configured to be able to run in the background and use the network, then your observers will continue to function just like when the app runs in the foreground. If you app is not set up as able to run in the background, then the OS typically keeps the socket open for a short time before closing it. In that case, your app will need to enter the foreground again before it can start receiving new messages.